# Is there a way to edit a variable with changing names in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to edit 200+ Excel files from a database, unfortunately the database provides the data in a strange way, meaning I need to delete the first 2 lines and I need to rename 20 variable names. 19 of those are staying the same but 1 variable name (always on the same position) in the excel sheet is changing. This changing variable needs to be named FY-0, name change to FY-1... is already included.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
in_path = 'ESG_untransfored'
out_path = 'ESG_transformed'
if not os.path.exists(out_path):
os.mkdir(out_path)

for filename in os.listdir(in_path):
    if filename.endswith('.xlsx'):
        df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(in_path, filename))
        df = df.iloc[2:]
        duf=duf.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 29':'FY-1'})
        duf=duf.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 30':'FY-2'})
        duf=duf.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 31':'FY-3'})
        duf=duf.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 32':'FY-4'})
        duf=duf.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 33':'FY-5'})
        duf=duf.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 34':'FY-6'})
        duf=duf.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 35':'FY-7'})
        duf=duf.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 36':'FY-8'})
        duf=duf.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 37':'FY-9'})
        duf=duf.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 38':'FY-10'})
        duf=duf.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 39':'FY-11'})
        duf=duf.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 40':'FY-12'})
        duf=duf.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 41':'FY-13'})
        duf=duf.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 42':'FY-14'})
        duf=duf.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 43':'FY-15'})
        duf=duf.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 44':'FY-16'})
        duf=duf.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 45':'FY-17'})
        duf=duf.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 46':'FY-18'})
        duf=duf.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 47':'FY-19'})
        duf=duf.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 48':'FY-20'})
        df.to_excel(os.path.join(out_path, filename),      index=False)
```

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample input and output for one excel file?

Comment: FYI `pd.read_excel` has a `skiprows` parameter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I understand your problem right (and that `duf` is supposed to be `df`), you could do something like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(in_path, filename))
df = df.iloc[2:]
cols = list(df.columns)
cols[0] = "FY-0"
df.columns = cols
```

This will always change the name of the first column to be `"FY-0"`. Not too elegant, but should do the trick.

(The reason you have to to `list(df.columns)` is that the columns attribute of the data frame is immutable, but lists aren't).